# convert .sav SPSS files into long or flat format CSVs

Tags: beginner, c, csv, converting

I'm a long standing PHP, JS, C#(Unity) dev looking to get outside objects and lower down. I've written a quick program to read binary data from a .sav file, and output the data section into CSV's in either long or flat format, with optional leading row indexes.

Wanted to learn more about C so I can start to play with micro controllers and GPIO.

It supports help, version, silent and debug modes (-h, -v, -s and -d respectively).

All seems to work, but I'd rather some experienced eyes catch what I might be doing schoolboy.

Repo:
https://github.com/erbarratt/savtocsv

Q's:

- Am I doing things right in terms of inclusion of headers from one to the next? They cascade at the min.
- Is the makefile ok? Do I need more params for gcc to be cross compatible?
- Is the linked list for variables the right way to do this?
- Am I processing -v and -s options correctly / standard?

Files in order of compilation:

#### common.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER

#define bswap_32(x) _byteswap_ulong(x)
#define bswap_64(x) _byteswap_uint64(x)

#elif defined(__APPLE__)

// Mac OS X / Darwin features
#include <libkern/OSByteOrder.h>
#define bswap_32(x) OSSwapInt32(x)
#define bswap_64(x) OSSwapInt64(x)

#elif defined(__sun) || defined(sun)

#include <sys/byteorder.h>
#define bswap_32(x) BSWAP_32(x)
#define bswap_64(x) BSWAP_64(x)

#elif defined(__FreeBSD__)

#include <sys/endian.h>
#define bswap_32(x) bswap32(x)
#define bswap_64(x) bswap64(x)

#elif defined(__OpenBSD__)

#include <sys/types.h>
#define bswap_32(x) swap32(x)
#define bswap_64(x) swap64(x)

#elif defined(__NetBSD__)

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <machine/bswap.h>
#if defined(__BSWAP_RENAME) && !defined(__bswap_32)
#define bswap_32(x) bswap32(x)
#define bswap_64(x) bswap64(x)
#endif

#else

#include <byteswap.h>

#endif
```

#### savtocsvcommon.h

```
#include "common.h"

extern bool debug;
extern bool silent;
extern bool longCsv;
extern bool includeRowIndex;
extern char *sav;
extern char *csv;
extern int lineLimit;

extern char ANSI_COLOR_RED[];
extern char ANSI_COLOR_GREEN[];
extern char ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW[];
extern char ANSI_COLOR_BLUE[];
extern char ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA[];
extern char ANSI_COLOR_CYAN[];
extern char ANSI_COLOR_RESET[];

void colorSet(char *col);
void printOut(char *str, char *bound, char *col);
void printOutErr(char *str, char *bound);
char *getFileExt(char *filename);
bool dubIsInt(double val);
char* intToStr8(int8_t num);
char* intToStr32(int num);
char* intToStr64(int64_t num);
char* doubleToStr(double num);
```

#### savtocsvcommon.c

```
bool debug = false;
bool silent = false;
bool longCsv = true;
bool includeRowIndex = false;
char *sav = NULL;
char *csv = "out";
int lineLimit = 0;

char ANSI_COLOR_RED[] = "\x1b[31m";
char ANSI_COLOR_GREEN[] = "\x1b[32m";
char ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW[] = "\x1b[33m";
char ANSI_COLOR_BLUE[] = "\x1b[34m";
char ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA[] = "\x1b[35m";
char ANSI_COLOR_CYAN[] = "\x1b[36m";
char ANSI_COLOR_RESET[] = "\x1b[0m";

/**
* Set the colour output of the console
* @param char *col The chosen colour
* @return void
*/
    void colorSet(char *col){
        
        if (strcmp(col, "red") == 0){
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RED);
                
        } else if (strcmp(col, "yellow") == 0){
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW);
                
        } else if (strcmp(col, "green") == 0){
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                
        } else if (strcmp(col, "blue") == 0){
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_BLUE);
                
        } else if (strcmp(col, "cyan") == 0){
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_CYAN);
                
        } else if (strcmp(col, "magenta") == 0){
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA);
            
        } else if (strcmp(col, "reset") == 0){
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                
        } else {
            
            printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                
        }
        
    }

/**
* Print out based on silent switch
* @param char *str The printf() message
* @param char *bound Any additional string to pass to printf()
* @param char *col The chosen colour
* @return void
*/
    void printOut(char *str, char *bound, char *col){
        
        if(!silent){
            colorSet(col);
            printf(str, bound);
            puts(ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
        }
        
    }
    
/**
* Print out to stderr based on silent switch
* @param char *str The printf() message
* @param char *bound Any additional string to pass to fprintf()
* @return void
*/
    void printOutErr(char *str, char *bound){
        
        if(!silent){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", ANSI_COLOR_RED);
            fprintf(stderr, str, bound);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
            fprintf(stderr,"\n");
        }
        
    }
    
/**
* Get file extension
* @param char *filename The filename in question
* @return char
*/
    char *getFileExt(char *filename){
        
        char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
        if(!dot || dot == filename) return "";
        return dot + 1;
        
    }
    
/**
* Check if double can safely be treated as int
* @param double val The double
* @return bool
*/
    bool dubIsInt(double val){
        int truncated = (int)val;
        return (val == truncated);
    }

/**
* Turn 8 bit int into string
* @param int8_t num The int
* @return char*
*/
    char* intToStr8(int8_t num){
    
        int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", num );
        char* str = malloc( length + 1 );
        snprintf( str, length + 1, "%d", num );
        return str;
        
    }
/**
* Turn 32 bit int into string
* @param int num The int
* @return char*
*/
    char* intToStr32(int num){
    
        int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", num );
        char* str = malloc( length + 1 );
        snprintf( str, length + 1, "%d", num );
        return str;
        
    }
    
/**
* Turn 64 bit int into string
* @param int64_t num The int
* @return char*
*/
    char* intToStr64(int64_t num){
    
        int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%" PRId64, num );
        char* str = malloc( length + 1 );
        snprintf( str, length + 1, "%" PRId64, num );
        return str;
        
    }
    
/**
* Turn double into string
* @param double num The int
* @return char*
*/
    char* doubleToStr(double num){
    
        int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%f", num );
        char* str = malloc( length+1);
        snprintf( str, length + 1, "%f", num );
        return str;
        
    }
```

#### savtocsvlib.h

```
#include "savtocsvcommon.h"

#define RECORD_TYPE_VARIABLE 2
#define RECORD_TYPE_VALUE_LABELS 3
#define RECORD_TYPE_VALUE_LABELS_INDEX 4
#define RECORD_TYPE_DOCUMENTS 6
#define RECORD_TYPE_ADDITIONAL 7
#define RECORD_TYPE_FINAL 999

#define COMPRESS_SKIP_CODE 0
#define COMPRESS_END_OF_FILE 252
#define COMPRESS_NOT_COMPRESSED 253
#define COMPRESS_ALL_BLANKS 254
#define COMPRESS_MISSING_VALUE 255

//Number of bytes really stored in each segment of a very long string variable.
#define REAL_VLS_CHUNK 255

/** @var struct Variable Variable structure definition */
    typedef struct Variable{
        int type;
        int measure;
        int cols;
        int alignment;
        struct Variable * next;
    } variable_t;

void closeFile();
void exitAndCloseFile(char *str, char *bound);
void addVariable(variable_t * head, int type);
void convertToCSV(char *filename);
void readHeader();
void readMeta();
void readVariable();
void readValueLabels();
void dataToCsvLong();
void dataToCsvFlat();
void readOver(int amt, char *msg);
void readWord(char *msg);
int readIntByte(char *msg);
int readIntByteNoOutput();
int readInt32(char *msg);
void readInt64(char *msg);
double readDouble(char *msg);
double readDoubleNoOuput();
```

#### savtocsvlib.c

```
#include "savtocsvlib.h"

/** @var bool bigEndian flag to see if file was oringinally stored on Big Endian OS... */
    bool bigEndian = false;

/** @var FILE* savPtr File pointer for sav file */
    FILE* savPtr;

/** @var int cursor Internal library cursor */
    int cursor = 0;

/** @var char wordBuffer[4] Buffer for storing 4byte strings */
    char wordBuffer[4];

/** @var int8_t intByteBuffer Buffer for storing 8 bit / 1 byte ints */
    int8_t intByteBuffer;

/** @var int int32Buffer Buffer for storing 32 bit / 4 byte ints */
    int int32Buffer;

/** @var int64_t int64Buffer Buffer for storing 64 bit / 8 byte ints */
    int64_t int64Buffer;

/** @var double flt64Buffer Buffer for storing 64 bit / 8 byte floating point numbers */
    double flt64Buffer;
    
/** @var int compressionSwitch Compression on or not */
    int compressionSwitch;
    
/** @var double compressionBias Used to decode data */
    double compressionBias;
    
/** @var int numberOfCases Num cases in sav file */
    int numberOfCases = 0;
    
/** @var int numberOfVariables Num vars in sav file */
    int numberOfVariables = 0;

/** @var variable_t* variablesList Linked list of Variable structures */
    variable_t * variablesList = NULL;

/**
* Close file
* @return void
*/
    void closeFile(){
        fclose(savPtr);
    }
    

/**
* Print error, close file and exit
* @return void
*/
    void exitAndCloseFile(char *str, char *bound){
        printOutErr(str, bound);
        closeFile();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
/**
* Add a variable to the Variables linked list
* @param variable_t * head Pointer to head of list
* @param int type Variable typecode to add one creation
* @return void
*/
    void addVariable(variable_t * head, int type) {
    
        variable_t * current = head;
        
        //find last element
            while (current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            }
        
        //add new var
            current->next = (variable_t *) malloc(sizeof(variable_t));
            current->next->type = type;
            current->next->measure = 0;
            current->next->cols = 0;
            current->next->alignment = 0;
            current->next->next = NULL;
        
    }

/**
* Main run through method
* @return void
*/
    void convertToCSV(char *filename){
        
        //try to open for read in binary mode
            savPtr = fopen(filename, "rb");
            
        //file open?
            if (savPtr == NULL) {
                exitAndCloseFile("Unable to open file (permission denied, try sudo): %s", filename);
            }
        
        //file passed isn't sav file
            if(strcmp(getFileExt(filename),"sav") != 0){
                exitAndCloseFile("Unable to open file: %s", filename);
            }
        
        //can't open file passed
            else if(savPtr == NULL){
                exitAndCloseFile("Unable to open file: %s", filename);
            }
            
        //log
            printOut("Opened .sav file: \n\t%s", filename, "cyan");
            
        //initialise linked list
            variablesList = (variable_t*)malloc(sizeof(variable_t));
            variablesList->type = 0;
            variablesList->measure = 0;
            variablesList->cols = 0;
            variablesList->alignment = 0;
            variablesList->next = NULL;
        
        //header
            readHeader();
            
        //meta
            readMeta();
            
        //data
            if(longCsv){
                dataToCsvLong();
            } else {
                dataToCsvFlat();
            }
            
        closeFile();
        
    }
    
/**
* Read from the sav file until the start of the data blocks
* @return void
*/
    void readHeader(){
        
        if(!silent){
            printOut("Reading file header:", "", "cyan");
        }
        
        //reset file pointer location to start
            fseek(savPtr, 0, SEEK_SET);
        
        //get file type
            readWord("File Identifier:");
            
            if (strcmp(wordBuffer, "$FL2") != 0){
                exitAndCloseFile("File must begin with chars $FL2 for a valid SPSS .sav file.", "");
            }
            
            //@4
        
        //read SPSS Version text
            readOver(60, "Header:");
            
            //@64
        
        //layout code should be 2 or 3
            int layout = readInt32("Layout Code:");
            if(layout != 2 && layout != 3){
                bigEndian = true;
                printOut("File stored as Big Endian found in layout code.", "", "yellow");
            }
            
            //@68
            
        // OBS
            readInt32("OBS:");
            
            //@72
            
        // compression
            compressionSwitch = readInt32("Compression:");
            
            //@76
            
        // weight
            readInt32("Weight:");
            
            //@80
            
        // cases
            numberOfCases = readInt32("Number of Cases:");
            
            //@84
        
        // compression bias
            compressionBias = readDouble("Compression Bias:");
            
            //@92
            
        // creation date
            readOver(9, "Creation Date:");
            readOver(8, "Creation Time:");
            
            //@109
            
        // file label
            readOver(64, "File Label:");
            
            //@173
            
        // padding
            readOver(3, "Padding:");
            
            //@176
            
        if(!silent){
            printOut("\t%s Cases found", intToStr32(numberOfCases), "cyan");
        }
        
    }
    
/**
* Read from the sav file until the start of the data blocks
* @return void
*/
    void readMeta(){
    
        if(!silent){
            printOut("Reading meta data:", "", "cyan");
        }
    
        bool stop = false;
        while (!stop) {
        
            if(debug){
                printOut("-------------------------", "", "blue");
                printOut("-------------------------", "", "blue");
            }
            
            int recordType = readInt32("Record type:");
            
            switch (recordType) {
                
                // Variable Record (2)
                    case RECORD_TYPE_VARIABLE:
                        readVariable();
                    break;
                        
                // Value and labels (3)
                    case RECORD_TYPE_VALUE_LABELS:
                        readValueLabels();
                    break;
                        
                // Read and parse document records (6)
                    case RECORD_TYPE_DOCUMENTS:
                        
                        {
                            // number of variables
                                int numberOfLines = readInt32("Number of Docs Vars:");
                            
                            // read the lines
                                int i;
                                for (i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
                                    readOver(80, "Doc Content:");
                                }
                            
                        }
                        
                    break;
                        
                // Read and parse additional records (7)
                    case RECORD_TYPE_ADDITIONAL:
                    
                        {
                        
                            int subtype = readInt32("SubType:");
                            //@4
                            
                            int size = readInt32("Size:");
                            //@8
                        
                            int count = readInt32("Count:");
                            //@12
                            
                            int datalen = size * count;
                            
                            switch (subtype) {
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 3 - Source system characteristics
                                    case 3:
                                        readOver(32, "Source system characteristics:");
                                    break;
                                    
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 4 - Source system floating pt constants
                                    case 4:
                                        readOver(24, "Source system floating pt constants:");
                                    break;
                                    
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 5 - Variable sets
                                    case 5:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Variable Sets:");
                                    break;
                                    
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 6 - Trends date information
                                    case 6:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Trends Date Info:");
                                    break;
                                    
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 7 - Multi response groups
                                    case 7:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Multi Response Groups:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 11 - Variable meta SPSS bits...
                                    case 11:
                                        
                                        if (size != 4) {
                                            exitAndCloseFile("Error reading record type 7 subtype 11: bad data element length [%s]. Expecting 4.", intToStr32(size));
                                        }
                                        
                                        if ((count % 3) != 0) {
                                            exitAndCloseFile("Error reading record type 7 subtype 11: number of data elements [%s] is not a multiple of 3.", intToStr32(size));

                                        }
                                    
                                        //go through vars and set meta
                                            variable_t * current = variablesList;
                                            current = current->next;
                                            
                                            int i;
                                            for(i = 0; i < count/3; ++i){
                                                
                                                if(debug){
                                                    printOut("~~~Var Meta~~~", "", "magenta");
                                                    printOut("\n~~~Var Type: %s \n", intToStr32(current->type), "yellow");
                                                }
                                                current->measure =  readInt32("~~~Var Measure:");
                                                current->cols =  readInt32("~~~Var Cols:");
                                                current->alignment =  readInt32("~~~Var Alignment:");
                                                
                                                current = current->next;
    
                                            }
                                        
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 13 - Extended names
                                    case 13:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Extended Names:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 14 - Extended strings
                                    case 14:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Extended Strings:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 16 - Number Of Cases
                                    case 16:
                                    
                                        readInt32("Byte Order:");
                                        readOver(4, "Skip:");
                                        readInt32("Count:");
                                        readOver(4, "Skip:");
                                        
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 17 - Dataset Attributes
                                    case 17:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Dataset Attributes:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 18 - Variable Attributes
                                    case 18:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Variable Attributes:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 19 -  Extended multiple response groups
                                    case 19:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Extended multiple response groups:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 20 -  Encoding, aka code page
                                    case 20:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Encoding, aka code page:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 21 - Extended value labels
                                    case 21:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Extended value labels:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 22 - Missing values for long strings
                                
                                    case 22:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Missing values for long strings:");
                                    break;
                                    
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 23 - Sort Index information
                                    case 23:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Sort Index information:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // SPSS Record Type 7 Subtype 24 - XML info
                                    case 24:
                                        readOver(datalen, "XML info:");
                                    break;
                                
                                // Other info
                                    default:
                                        readOver(datalen, "Misc info:");
                                    break;
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    break;
                        
                // Finish
                    case RECORD_TYPE_FINAL:
                        
                        stop = true;
                    
                        int test = readInt32("Test for final rec type:");
                        
                        if (test != 0) {
                            exitAndCloseFile("Error reading record type 999: Non-zero value found.", "");
                        }
                        
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    exitAndCloseFile("Read error: invalid record type [%s]", intToStr32(recordType));
                break;
            
            }
            
        }
        
        if(!silent){
            printOut("\t%s Variables found", intToStr32(numberOfVariables), "cyan");
        }
    
    }

/**
 * SPSS Record Type 2 - Variable information
 * @throws \Exception
 * @return void
 */
    void readVariable()
    {
        
        int typeCode = readInt32("---Var Type Code:");
        //if numeric, type code here = 0
        //if string, type code is length of string.
        
        //@4
        
        //if TYPECODE is -1, record is a continuation of a string var
            if(typeCode == -1) {
            
                //read and ignore the next 24 bytes
                    readOver(24, "---String Continuation Var Skip 24:");
                    
        //otherwise normal var
            } else {
                
                addVariable(variablesList, typeCode);
                
                numberOfVariables++;
                
                // read label flag
                    int hasLabel = readInt32("---Var Has Label:");
                    //could throw exception here as missing label?
                    
                    //@8
                
                // read missing value format code
                    int missingValueFormatCode = readInt32("---Missing Format Code:");
                    
                    if (abs(missingValueFormatCode) > 3) {
                        exitAndCloseFile("Error reading variable Record: invalid missing value format code [%s]. Range is -3 to 3.", intToStr32(missingValueFormatCode));
                    }
                    
                    //@12
                
                // read print format code
                    readInt32("---Print Format Code:");
                
                    //@16
                
                // read write format code
                    readInt32("---Write Format Code:");
                
                    //@20
                
                // read varname
                    readOver(8, "---Var Short Name:");
                
                    //@28
                
                // read label length and label only if a label exists
                    if (hasLabel == 1) {
                        
                        int labelLength = readInt32("---Label Length:");
                        //@32
                        
                        //need to ensure we read word-divisable amount of bytes
                            int rem = 4-(labelLength % 4);
                            if(rem == 4){
                                rem = 0;
                            }
                            
                            readOver(labelLength, "---Label:");
                            readOver(rem, "---label Skip:");
                        
                    }
                
                // missing values
                    if (missingValueFormatCode != 0) {
                        int i;
                        for (i = 0; i < abs(missingValueFormatCode); ++i) {
                            readInt64("---Missing Values:");
                        }
                    }
                
            }
        
    }

/**
 * SPSS Record Type 3 - Value labels
 * @return void
 */
    void readValueLabels()
    {
    
        // number of labels
            int numberOfLabels = readInt32("+++Number of Labels:");
            //@4
    
        // labels
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfLabels; i++) {
    
                // read the label value
                    double labelValue = readDouble("+++Value:");
                    //@8
                
                // read the length of a value label
                // the following byte in an unsigned integer (max value is 60)
                    int8_t labelLength = readIntByte("+++Label Length:");
                    int8_t max = 60;
                
                    if (labelLength > max) {
                        exitAndCloseFile("The length of a value label(%s) must be less than 60.", doubleToStr(labelValue));
                    }
                
                //need to ensure we read word-divisable amount of bytes
                    int rem = 8-((labelLength+1) % 8);
                    if(rem == 8){
                        rem = 0;
                    }
                    
                    readOver(labelLength, "+++Label:");
                    readOver(rem, "+++Label Skip:");
                
            }
    
        // read type 4 record (that must follow type 3!)
        // record type
            int recordTypeCode = readInt32("+++Record Type Code (Should be 4):");
            if (recordTypeCode != 4) {
                exitAndCloseFile("Error reading Variable Index record: bad record type [%s]. Expecting Record Type 4.", intToStr32(recordTypeCode));
            }
    
        // number of variables to add to?
            int numVars = readInt32("+++Number of Variables:");
    
        // variableRecord indexes
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < numVars; j++) {
                
                readInt32("+++Var Index:");
            
            }
    
    }
    
/**
 * Convert data to long format csv's
 * @return void
 */
    void dataToCsvLong(){
    
        int fileNumber = 1;
        int caseid = 1;
        int rowCount = 1;
        
        int cluster[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int clusterIndex = 8;
        
        int totalRows = numberOfVariables * numberOfCases;
        int filesAmount;
        
        if(totalRows > lineLimit){
            filesAmount = (totalRows / lineLimit) + 1;
        } else {
            filesAmount = 1;
        }
        FILE * csvs[filesAmount];
        
        char filename[100] = "";
        
        //first filename
            strcat(filename, csv);
            strcat(filename, intToStr32(fileNumber));
            strcat(filename, ".csv");
        
        //first file
            csvs[0] = fopen(filename, "w");
            
        //can we open and edit?
            if (csvs[0] == NULL) {
                exitAndCloseFile("Unable to open file (permission denied, try sudo): %s", filename);
            }
        
        if(!silent){
            printOut("Building Long CSV:", "", "cyan");
            printOut("\t%s", filename, "cyan");
        }
        
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i <= numberOfCases; i++){
            
            //loop through vars, skipping head of list
                //variable_t * current = variablesList;
                //current = current->next;
            
                int variableId = 1;
                int j;
                for(j = 0; j < numberOfVariables; j++){
                    
                    //current->type
                    
                    double numData;
                    bool insertNull = false;
                    
                    if(compressionSwitch > 0){
                    
                        if(clusterIndex > 7){
                        
                            cluster[0] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[1] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[2] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[3] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[4] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[5] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[6] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[7] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            
                            clusterIndex = 0;
                        
                        }
                        
                        // convert byte to an unsigned byte in an int
                            int byteValue = (0x000000FF & (int)cluster[clusterIndex]);
                            
                            clusterIndex++;
                        
                        switch (byteValue) {
                            
                            // skip this code
                                case COMPRESS_SKIP_CODE:
                                break;
                                
                            // end of file, no more data to follow. This should not happen.
                                case COMPRESS_END_OF_FILE:
                                    exitAndCloseFile("Error reading data: unexpected end of compressed data file (cluster code 252)", "");
                                break;
                                
                            // data cannot be compressed, the value follows the cluster
                                case COMPRESS_NOT_COMPRESSED:
                                    numData = readDoubleNoOuput();
                                break;
                                
                            // all blanks
                                case COMPRESS_ALL_BLANKS:
                                    numData = 0;
                                break;
                                
                            // system missing value
                                case COMPRESS_MISSING_VALUE:
                                    //used to be 'NULL' but LOAD DATA INFILE requires \N instead, otherwise a '0' get's inserted instead
                                    insertNull = true;
                                break;
                                
                            // 1-251 value is code minus the compression BIAS (normally always equal to 100)
                                default:
                                    numData = byteValue - compressionBias;
                                break;
                            
                        }
                    
                    } else {
                        numData = readDoubleNoOuput();
                    }
                    
                    //write to file
                    
                        if(includeRowIndex){
                            
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"%d,",rowCount);
                            
                        }
                            
                        if(insertNull){
                        
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"%d,%d,\\N\n", caseid, variableId);
                        
                        } else if (dubIsInt(numData)) {
                            
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"%d,%d,%d\n", caseid, variableId, (int)numData);
                        
                        } else {
                            
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"%d,%d,%f\n", caseid, variableId, numData);
                            
                        }
                    
                    //switch to new file
                    if(rowCount % lineLimit == 0){
                        
                        //close current file
                            fclose(csvs[fileNumber-1]);
                        
                        //make and open new file
                            fileNumber++;
                        
                            char filenameHere[100] = "";
                        
                            strcat(filenameHere, csv);
                            strcat(filenameHere, intToStr32(fileNumber));
                            strcat(filenameHere, ".csv");
                        
                            csvs[fileNumber-1] = fopen(filenameHere,"w");
                            
                            if (csvs[fileNumber-1] == NULL) {
                                exitAndCloseFile("Unable to open file (permission denied, try sudo): %s", filenameHere);
                            }
                        
                        if(!silent){
                            printOut("Building Long CSV:", "", "cyan");
                            printOut("\t%s", filenameHere, "cyan");
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    //current = current->next;
                    variableId++;
                    rowCount++;
                
                }
            
            caseid++;
        
        }
        
        if(!silent){
            printOut("Wrote %s rows.", intToStr32(totalRows), "green");
            printOut("Wrote %s files.", intToStr32(filesAmount), "green");
        }
        
        //close current file
            fclose(csvs[fileNumber-1]);
    
    }
    
/**
 * Convert data to flat format csv's
 * @return void
 */
    void dataToCsvFlat(){
    
        int fileNumber = 1;
        
        int cluster[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int clusterIndex = 8;
        
        int filesAmount;
        
        if(numberOfCases > lineLimit){
            filesAmount = (numberOfCases / lineLimit) + 1;
        } else {
            filesAmount = 1;
        }
        
        FILE * csvs[filesAmount];
        
        char filename[100] = "";
        
        //first filename
            strcat(filename, csv);
            strcat(filename, intToStr32(fileNumber));
            strcat(filename, ".csv");
        
        //first file
            csvs[0] = fopen(filename, "w");
            
        //try to open
            if (csvs[0] == NULL) {
                exitAndCloseFile("Unable to open file (permission denied, try sudo): %s", filename);
            }
        
        if(!silent){
            printOut("Building Flat CSV:", "", "cyan");
            printOut("\t%s", filename, "cyan");
        }
        
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i <= numberOfCases; i++){
            
            //loop through vars, skipping head of list
                //variable_t * current = variablesList;
                //current = current->next;
                
                if(includeRowIndex){
                    fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"%d,", i);
                }
                
                int j;
                for(j = 0; j < numberOfVariables; j++){
                    
                    //current->type
                    
                    double numData;
                    bool insertNull = false;
                    
                    if(compressionSwitch > 0){
                    
                        if(clusterIndex > 7){
                        
                            cluster[0] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[1] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[2] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[3] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[4] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[5] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[6] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            cluster[7] = readIntByteNoOutput();
                            
                            clusterIndex = 0;
                        
                        }
                        
                        // convert byte to an unsigned byte in an int
                            int byteValue = (0x000000FF & (int)cluster[clusterIndex]);
                            
                            clusterIndex++;
                        
                        switch (byteValue) {
                            
                            // skip this code
                                case COMPRESS_SKIP_CODE:
                                break;
                                
                            // end of file, no more data to follow. This should not happen.
                                case COMPRESS_END_OF_FILE:
                                    exitAndCloseFile("Error reading data: unexpected end of compressed data file (cluster code 252)", "");
                                break;
                                
                            // data cannot be compressed, the value follows the cluster
                                case COMPRESS_NOT_COMPRESSED:
                                    numData = readDoubleNoOuput();
                                break;
                                
                            // all blanks
                                case COMPRESS_ALL_BLANKS:
                                    numData = 0;
                                break;
                                
                            // system missing value
                                case COMPRESS_MISSING_VALUE:
                                    //used to be 'NULL' but LOAD DATA INFILE requires \N instead, otherwise a '0' get's inserted instead
                                    insertNull = true;
                                break;
                                
                            // 1-251 value is code minus the compression BIAS (normally always equal to 100)
                                default:
                                    numData = byteValue - compressionBias;
                                break;
                            
                        }
                    
                    } else {
                        numData = readDoubleNoOuput();
                    }
                    
                    //write to file
                    
                        if(j > 0){
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],",");
                        }
                    
                        if(insertNull){
                            
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"\\N");
                        
                        } else if (dubIsInt(numData)) {
                            
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"%d",(int)numData);
                        
                        } else {
                            
                            fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"%f",numData);
                        
                        }
                
                }
                
                //newline
                    fprintf(csvs[fileNumber-1],"\n");
                
                //switch to new file
                    if(i % lineLimit == 0){
                        
                        //close current file
                            fclose(csvs[fileNumber-1]);
                        
                        //make and open new file
                            fileNumber++;
                        
                            char filenameHere[100] = "";
                        
                            strcat(filenameHere, csv);
                            strcat(filenameHere, intToStr32(fileNumber));
                            strcat(filenameHere, ".csv");
                        
                            csvs[fileNumber-1] = fopen(filenameHere,"w");
                            
                            if (csvs[fileNumber-1] == NULL) {
                                exitAndCloseFile("Unable to open file (permission denied, try sudo): %s", filenameHere);
                            }
                        
                        if(!silent){
                            printOut("Building Flat CSV:", "", "cyan");
                            printOut("\t%s", filenameHere, "cyan");
                        }
                        
                    }
        
        }
        
        if(!silent){
            printOut("Wrote %s rows.", intToStr32(numberOfCases), "green");
            printOut("Wrote %s files.", intToStr32(filesAmount), "green");
        }
        
        //close current file
            fclose(csvs[fileNumber-1]);
    
    }
    
/**
* Read a number of bytes and print but not store in memory
* @param int amt Amount of bytes
* @param char *msg Message to prepend to debug output
* @return void
*/
    void readOver(int amt, char *msg){
            
        //only initialise with blank data if debug, otherwise doesn't matter.
            if(debug){
                
                //read amounts into temp var
                char temp[amt+1];
            
                int i;
                for(i = 0; i < amt; i++){
                    temp[i] = ' ';
                }
                
                temp[amt] = '\0';
                
                fread(&temp, amt, 1, savPtr);
                
                if(!silent){
                    printOut(msg, "", "yellow");
                    printOut("\t%s", temp, "magenta");
                    printf("\t<%d bytes read, %d bytes total>\n\n", amt, cursor);
                }
                
            } else {
                fseek(savPtr, amt, SEEK_CUR);
            }
            
        cursor += amt;
        
    }
    
/**
* Read 4 bytes as a string
* @param char *msg Message to prepend to debug output
* @return void
*/
    void readWord(char *msg){
    
        //read into mem loc of word buffer. Word buffer always 4 in length, so no need to clear
            fread(&wordBuffer, 4, 1, savPtr);
    
            cursor += 4;
    
        //output for debug info
            if(debug && !silent){
                printOut(msg, "", "yellow");
                printOut("\t%s", wordBuffer, "magenta");
                printf("\t<4 bytes read, %d bytes total>\n\n", cursor);
            }
            
    }

/**
* Read 1 byte as an int
* @param char *msg Message to prepend to debug output
* @return void
*/
    int readIntByte(char *msg){
        
        //read 4 bytes into memory location of int32buffer
        fread(&intByteBuffer, 1, 1, savPtr);
        
        cursor += 1;
        
        //output for debug info
        if(debug && !silent){
            printOut(msg, "", "yellow");
            printf("\t%d\n", intByteBuffer);
            printf("\t<1 byte read, %d bytes total>\n\n", cursor);
        }
        
        return intByteBuffer;
        
    }
    
/**
* Read 1 byte as an int
* @return void
*/
    int readIntByteNoOutput(){
        
        //read 4 bytes into memory location of int32buffer
        fread(&intByteBuffer, 1, 1, savPtr);
        
        cursor += 1;
        
        return intByteBuffer;
        
    }
    
/**
* Read 4 bytes as an int 
* @param char *msg Message to prepend to debug output
* @return void
*/
    int readInt32(char *msg){
    
        //read 4 bytes into memory location of int32buffer
            fread(&int32Buffer, 4, 1, savPtr);
    
            cursor += 4;
        
        //if file been stored on a big endian system (as found in header), swap bytes for 32 bits (4 bytes) in the buffer
            if(bigEndian){
                bswap_32(int32Buffer);
            }
    
        //output for debug info
            if(debug && !silent){
                printOut(msg, "", "yellow");
                printOut("\t%s", intToStr32(int32Buffer), "magenta");
                printf("\t<4 bytes read, %d bytes total>\n\n", cursor);
            }
        
        return int32Buffer;
        
    }
    
/**
* Read 8 bytes as a double
* @param char *msg Message to prepend to debug output
* @return void
*/
    void readInt64(char *msg){
    
        fread(&int64Buffer, 8, 1, savPtr);
    
        cursor += 8;
    
        //if file been stored on a big endian system (as found in header), swap bytes for 64 bits (8 bytes) in the buffer
            if(bigEndian){
                bswap_64(int64Buffer);
            }
        
        if(debug && !silent){
            printOut(msg, "", "yellow");
            printOut("\t%s", intToStr64(int64Buffer), "magenta");
            printf("\t<8 bytes read, %d bytes total>\n\n", cursor);
        }
        
        
    }
    
/**
* Read 8 bytes as a double
* @param char *msg Message to prepend to debug output
* @return void
*/
    double readDouble(char *msg){
        
        fread(&flt64Buffer, 8, 1, savPtr);
        
        cursor += 8;
        
        //if file been stored on a big endian system (as found in header), swap bytes for 64 bits (8 bytes) in the buffer
        if(bigEndian){
            bswap_64(flt64Buffer);
        }
        
        if(debug && !silent){
            printOut(msg, "", "yellow");
            printOut("\t%s", doubleToStr(flt64Buffer), "magenta");
            printf("\t<8 bytes read, %d bytes total>\n\n", cursor);
        }
        
        return flt64Buffer;
        
    }
    
/**
* Read 8 bytes as a double
* @return void
*/
    double readDoubleNoOuput(){
        
        fread(&flt64Buffer, 8, 1, savPtr);
        
        cursor += 8;
        
        //if file been stored on a big endian system (as found in header), swap bytes for 64 bits (8 bytes) in the buffer
        if(bigEndian){
            bswap_64(flt64Buffer);
        }
        
        return flt64Buffer;
        
    }
```

#### savtocsv.c

```
#include "savtocsvlib.h"

void parseOpts(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    //main parse of options before opening / reading file
        parseOpts(argc, argv);
    
    //open the file or exit
        convertToCSV(sav);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
    
}

/**
* Print out based on silent switch
* @param int argc Count of arguments
* @param argv *argv Array of pointers of arguments
* @return void
*/
void parseOpts(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    int opt;
    
    // If the first character of optstring is '-', then each nonoption argv-element is handled as if
    // it were the argument of an option with character code 1. (This is used by programs that were written to expect options and other argv-elements in any order and that care about the ordering of the two.)
        if(argc == 2){
            
            //check for version output or help
                while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "-vh")) != -1) {
                    
                    if(opt == 'v'){
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("savtocsv ");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("version ");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW);
                        printf("version 1.5.6 ");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("2021-03-22\n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    
                    else if(opt == 'h'){
                        
                        printOut("\n----------SAV To CSV Help----------\n", "", "green");
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW);
                        printf("Usage:\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printOut("\tcommand [options] [arguments]\n", "", "magenta");
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW);
                        printf("Options:\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-f\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tSet the input .sav filename (eg file.sav)\n");
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-o\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tSet the output csv prefix (appended by x.csv where x is filenumber determined by Line Limit) ");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW);
                        printf("[default: out]\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-l\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tSet Line Limit per csv file.  ");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW);
                        printf("[default: 1000000]\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-s\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tSet silent mode for no output.\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-d\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tSet debug mode for additional output. Will not output if Silent mode on.\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-F\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tSet csv output format to flat instead of long.\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-R\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tSet csv output to include row index.\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-v\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tOutput version. Must be sole option.\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_GREEN);
                        printf("\t-h\t");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        printf("\tOutput help. Must be sole option.\n");
                        printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
                        
                        printf("\n");
                        
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    
                }
            
        }
    
    //reset getopt index for next while loop
        optind = 1;
    
    //check for silent first
        while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "-sfoldFR")) != -1) {
            
            if(opt == 's'){
                silent = true;
            }
            
        }
    
    //reset getopt index for next while loop
        optind = 1;
    
    //ullo
        printOut("\n----------SAV To CSV----------", "", "green");
    
    //if it's not -v or -h then is the num of args correct?
        if(argc <= 2){
            printOutErr("Missing required options.", "");
            printOutErr("Usage: savtocsv [-v] | [-f] [file...] [-o] [file...] [-l] [int] [-sdFR]", "");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
    //go through normal options
        while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "-f:o:l:svdFR")) != -1) {
            
            switch (opt) {
                
                //get file pointer
                    case 'f':
                        sav = optarg;
                        printOut("Input file set: \n\t%s", optarg, "magenta");
                    break;
                    
                //get output filename
                    case 'o':
                        csv = optarg;
                    break;
                    
                //silent switch for stdout
                    case 's':
                        silent = true;
                    break;
                    
                //debug switch for stdout
                    case 'd':
                        debug = true;
                    break;
                    
                //csv file format
                    case 'F':
                        longCsv = false;
                    break;
                    
                //output row index for each row
                    case 'R':
                        includeRowIndex = true;
                    break;
                    
                //how pany lines per csv?
                    case 'l':
                        
                        lineLimit = atoi(optarg);
                        if(lineLimit == 0){
                            printOutErr("-l argument must be number", optarg);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        } else {
                            printOut("CSV Line Length set to: \n\t%s", optarg, "magenta");
                        }
                    
                    break;
                    
                //option not in optstring
                    case '?':
                        
                        printOutErr("Option not in option list of -f -o -l", "");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    
                    break;
                
            }
            
        }
    
    //check sav file option
        if(sav == NULL){
            printOutErr("Missing required option -f", "");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
    //output csv prefix
        if(strcmp(csv, "out") == 0){
            printOut("Output file prefix default: \n\tout", "", "yellow");
        } else {
            printOut("Output file prefix set: \n\t%s", csv, "magenta");
        }
    
    //check line limit or set default
        if(lineLimit == 0){
            lineLimit = 1000000;
            char *lltxt = "1000000";
            printOut("CSV Line Length default: \n\t%s", lltxt, "yellow");
        }
        
    //flat file or long file
        if(longCsv){
            printOut("CSV file format default: \n\tLong.", "", "yellow");
        } else {
            printOut("CSV file format set: \n\tFlat", "", "magenta");
        }
    
    //flat file or long file
        if(!includeRowIndex){
            printOut("CSV include row index default: \n\tFALSE.", "", "yellow");
        } else {
            printOut("CSV include row index set: \n\tTRUE", "", "magenta");
        }
    
}
```

#### makefile

```
savtocsv: savtocsv.o savtocsvlib.o savtocsvcommon.o
        gcc -o savtocsv savtocsv.o savtocsvlib.o savtocsvcommon.o -O3 -std=gnu90;
        -rm *.o $(objects)
savtocsv.o: savtocsv.c savtocsvlib.h
        gcc -c -g savtocsv.c -std=gnu90;
savtocsvlib.o: savtocsvlib.c savtocsvlib.h
        gcc -c -g savtocsvlib.c -std=gnu90;
savtocsvcommon.o: savtocsvcommon.c savtocsvcommon.h
        gcc -c -g savtocsvcommon.c -std=gnu90;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compile with warnings enabled.  Then fix those warnings.

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu90
```

several header files are being included but their contents are not being used.  This is a very bad programming practice.

The makefile needs a  `.clean` label+commands for elimination of produced/reproducable files

The makefile needs a .ALL label as that is customary for ease of use of the makefile

The posted code discusses a `library` but the makefile never produces that library and the 'link' statements never make use of that library

the code that is outputting the color commands would be well served to have an `num` of the colors and use a switch() statement rather than all those `if/else` statements

the production of the linked list does not properly handle the event when the first 'node' is inserted

The `typedef` for the data to be output to the file contains a pointer.  This will not work correctly when reading back the produced file.  Rather, the data needs to be 'serialized' when writing to the file